# Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null

Tags: javascript, null, getelementsbytagname

I am trying some basic Javascript with selecting elements and tags but it's giving me issues.
Specifically I get this error in the dev tools using chrome or firefox:

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null*

The weird thing is that when I type the javascript command into the console on the browsers, it works without a problem. (Selecting the p tags within wrapper div)

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="default.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="selection.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <p>Hello, this is a paragraph</p>
        <p>Another one!</p>
        <p>This is yet another paragraph</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then my Javascript is:

```
window.onload = initP();

function initP() {
    var para = document.getElementById('wrapper').getElementsByTagName('p');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
window.onload = initP;
```

instead of

```
window.onload = initP();
```

as you are calling the function and not assigning it.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the function, not assigning it.

```
window.onload = initP();
```

needs to be

```
window.onload = initP;
```

The downside to the way you are attaching events is that if anything else before this registerd to the onload event, you will override it. Better to use [element.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/elemento.addEventListener)